# connection failed for: domain.com (NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for true:TrueClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I have no idea what happened and this is leaving me hairless!

I was trying to make the cap:deploy command work, then, out of nowhere, i get this error: 
`connection failed for: domain.com (NoMethodError: undefined method`>' for true:TrueClass) `

I did not edit the code at all. To try to pinpoint where the problem is, I started deleting line by line in the deploy.rb file and i realized that if there is not at least one of these 3 lines present, the error doesn't happen.

```
role :web, "domain.com"
role :app, "domain.com"
role :db,  "domain.com", :primary => true
```

and then of course it gives me another error about servers not being present. any idea what could be giving me this error?

Just prior to getting this error I was trying to set this right...

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_bin_path, "$HOME/.rvm/bin/"
set :rvm_path, "/usr/local/rvm/"
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.2-p290'
set :rvm_type, :user
```

but if i delete those lines and run cap deploy:setup again it still gives me the same error.

NO IDEA WHAT CAUSED IT!

Comment: Post the full backtrace - so that we can tell where the > is propagating from

Comment: What happens when you remove `, :primary => true` from the role :db?

Comment: Found the error!! Thanks Steph, after reading your comment I checked everything on the deploy file that had "true" in it and found out I had set :verbose, true instead of set :scm_verbose, true.

Comment: @StephRose elaborate a little on an answer so I can pay you the bounty

Comment: I did. Thanks, @leonel, and glad you knew where to look after we got that far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you see an error that says:

```
undefined method > for [class]
```

I've usually found that it's due to a definition's `symbol => value`

In this case, yours says `> for true:TrueClass`, so try taking off the `, :primary => true`

If that's the culprit, either check your settings in your deploy file or see if the symbol you defined is one that actually exists / applies, or if your syntax is correct.

In one case for mine, I had an `if` statement like:

```
XXX, if :symbol > 0
```

in a model that caused the error, and I needed to convert it into a `Proc`

(I expanded a little extra just in case others have the same undefined method for a different reason.)